# Sylius override Template

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, sylius

I have the latest (1.0.0-dev) Sylius with the latest LTS Symfony (2.8.9) installed and I am trying to understand how to override any of the tepmplates. I found this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbujTxpd3WY but this seems outdated.

For understanding it, I would like to change the `<title>` from Sylius to something else.

**AppBundle.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SyliusShopBundle';
    }
}
```

**Folder**

[image: Folder]

**layout.html.twig (to override)**

`<title>MYNEWTITLE</title>`

but even after `php app/console cache:clear` it does not change. Can anyone point me to a recent tutorial or have a look where I am wrong?

Comment: Have you added your `AppBundle` to `AppKernel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not recommend using Bundle's inheritance for this purpose, please use `app/Resources` folder to override or theming.

Have a look here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/template.html

For theming, here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusThemeBundle/index.html